# Almost every linear map $V\rightarrow V$ (in a certain affine subspace of such maps) is invertible

Tags: reference-request, linear-transformations, inverse

I'm writing up a paper. There is a result that I want to be rigorous about, but I'm not exactly sure how. Here is the set-up:

I have some real Euclidean space $V$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the set of all linear maps $\operatorname{L}(V)$ from $V$ to itself, which is isomorphic to the set of $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$. This is also a real Euclidean space and is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. Finally, let $A\subset\operatorname{L}(V)$ be some affine subspace that does not contain the origin. (In my paper, this is essentially the affine space of all linear maps $f:V\rightarrow V$ satisfying $f^*(v)=v$ for some fixed choice of nonzero vector $v\in V$.)

What I want to say is this: "*Almost all maps in $A$ are invertible (in the sense that, with respect to the induced Lebesgue measure on $A$, the set of non-invertible maps has measure zero).*"

This is certainly true. But my coauthor is not convinced this is as trivial as I think it is---and would like us to provide 'rigorous' reasoning for this.

My reasoning: We may consider $A$ as an affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. The determinant $\operatorname{det}:\mathbb{R}^{n^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a polynomial, and thus $\operatorname{det}$ is either constant on $A$ or the set of zeros on $A$ has measure zero. The desired result follows from the observation that a linear transformation is invertible if and only if its determinant is nonzero.

Is this valid reasoning? Is there something accessible that I could cite here?

---

As an aside, I wanted to mention where this is coming from. In quantum information theory, a *quantum channel* is a linear map $\Phi:M_m\rightarrow M_m$ that is completely positive and trace preserving. In particular, every quantum channel is also *Hermitian preserving*, so we may view it as a linear map on the set of $m\times m$ Hermitian matrices, which is a real Euclidean space. What I want to say is the following: *Almost all quantum channels are invertible as linear maps.* (Although, the inverse mapping is usually not also a channel.)

Comment: If $A$ were an arbitrary affine subspace, this wouldn't work, because it might, for example, consist of matrices in which the first two rows are equal.  An affine space that doesn't contain the origin looks more promising.

Comment: Ah, you are right! I'm really only concerned with affine subspaces of linear maps whose adjoints have $v$ as a fixed point (for some fixed choice of nonzero vector $v$). These affine spaces don't contain the origin. I'll change the title and question accordingly.

Comment: I think you could account for either case as follows: there exists some parameterization of the affine space. The determinant is a polynomial of the variables in this parameterization. This polynomial must be constant (possibly zero) or have a zero-set of measure zero.

Comment: The important point is not whether the affine space contains $0$, but whether it contains an invertible map.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing this in your case.
You are looking at $A_v= \{ T\in L(V) : Tv=v \}$ where $v$ is a non-zero vector. Extend $v$ to a basis. Then with respect to this basis $T\in A_v$ iff it has a matrix of the form $$[T]= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & * \\ 0 &B\end{bmatrix}$$ where $B\in M_{n-1}(\mathbb R)$

So you have identified $A_v \cong\mathbb R^{n^2-n}$ and $T\in A_v$ is invertible iff $\det B \neq 0$. So it is the complement of the zero set of a polynomial in $\mathbb R^{n^2-n}$ and hence has measure $0$.

EDIT: Let's see your problem in a more general framework where $V$ is some vector space over an infinite field $k$ and you ask the same question. $L(V)=M_n(k)$ is equipped with Zariski topology. It is easy to see that $M_n(k)$ is irreducible. So any non empty open set is dense. In particular $GL_n(k)=\{ T \in L(V) : \det(T)\neq 0 \}$ is a dense open subset. Since $A \subset M_n(k)$ is an affine linear subspace, it is also irreducible. So if $A\cap GL_n(k)$ is non-empty, then it is a dense open subset of $A$. The upshot is the existence of one invertible map gives you density of invertible maps in that affine subspace.